# Meaning of "dogmatic" in "there was a dogmatic gathering in the neighborhood"

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, adjectives

> and whenever she heard a large word she said it over to herself many times, and so was able to keep it until there was a **dogmatic gathering** in the neighborhood, then she would get it off, and surprise and **distress** them all, from pocket-pup to mastiff, which rewarded her for all her trouble.

From *A Dog's Tale* by Mark Twain.

Is it safe to assume that *dogmatic* in this context has nothing to do with *dogma*? Also, does the word *distress* mean "impress" here?

Comment: Have you looked up those two words in a dictionary? What did they say?

Comment: The 'dogmatic gathering' is a gathering of religious people, a religious meeting, I believe. She would make others impressed and a bit envious, maybe, of her knowledge of long words, hence, *distressed*; it's a humorous use of the term, I presume, Mark Twain being the great satirist.

Comment: I'm looking for the meaning in this context, not what is in the dictionary. The book is the story of a dog. her mother likes to impress other dogs with long words which she doesn't even understand. dogmatic gathering here means just a pack of dogs or something like that. it cant be anything else, but just to be sure, I am asking...

Comment: ok so the dogs are gathered by the people who have a dogmatic gathering. I see. and the word distress means impressed and a little envious?

Comment: Then it's likely a play on words, so I suggest you look up "dogmatic" in the dictionary

Comment: I have dozens of dictionaries and I look up words in them all the time because I try to translate this book. I have Oxford, longman, Encarta etc. when I put a question here, I'm usually desperate for answer.

Comment: Dear WS2, do you agree with Copperkettle? he has a very interesting point I think that is it.

Comment: **dogmatic**: *opinionated, peremptory, assertive, insistent, emphatic, adamant, doctrinaire, authoritarian, imperious, dictatorial, uncompromising, unyielding, inflexible, rigid*; More, but **nothing to do with religion**, nor with dogs.

Comment: With respect to all those who have suggested a dictionary, I can well appreciate that @Hamed has gone that route. No dictionary will explain this particular use as it is a play on words. Mark Twain is writing about 'dogs'. A 'dogmatic gathering' I suspect may have had a particular meaning in America, at the time of MT. The ODE doesn't even touch the expression.

Comment: @WS2 if it's a play on words, then don't you think it's likely a double meaning of sorts? Therefore he should consult a dictionary for the definition of the word (which Kris has already provided). This way he can appreciate both sides of the meaning.

Comment: @Dodgie But it is this term 'dogmatic gathering' that is relevant here. Does anyone know anything about 'dogmatic gatherings'? I can only guess at what they were.

Comment: Hamed – please (briefly) indicate any research you've already done **in the question**, to save answerers wasting time covering the same ground. And please ask one question at a time.

Comment: It's certainly a play on words, MT being who he was. Whether, as WS2 suspects, a 'dogmatic meeting' was in the vernacular (ie a collocation / compound), or a nonce expression (as Google results, seemingly all tied to this one instantiation, suggest) is not easy to decide.

Comment: I think based on the whole story we should think as simple as a dog and try to see things from his perspective. this way we simply can decide on the meaning of dogmatic gathering being an ambiguous expression of One: some dogs gathered together Two:her mother being a proud dog with no education who just uses other's ignorance to impress them with saying long words she doesn't even understand. so this makes the gathering of the dogs somewhat dogmatic.

Comment: RE: _I have dozens of dictionaries and I look up words in them all the time .. when I put a question here, I'm usually desperate for answer_. When you put a question here, you should include some of those definitions. Why? (1) It shows you've done your own research; (2) it makes your question easier to answer; (3) it makes your question more interesting to the community. It helps to what you've already discovered and why you're still confused. It wouldn't hurt to perhaps a few more words about the source, too. Don't assume everyone here has read it.

Comment: Google Book search does not find any other uses of "dogmatic gathering". It is safe to assume the phrase was coined by Mark Twain for humorous effect, and has no inherent meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Twain is having a little fun here, using a "large word" in the same way that the character he is writing about would use it; that is, in a place where it sounds like it might or should make sense but really is completely inappropriate.

The character in question being a dog, she does not actually understand the large words she is throwing about.  Such a being might well assume that "dogmatic" means "related to dogs", and therefore would use the phrase "dogmatic meeting" to mean a bunch of dogs getting together to talk about things.

As to the second portion of the question, I see no reason to think that the current meaning of *distress* is inappropriate in some way; the other dogs in the meeting could easily be distressed by this dog's repeated use of sesquipedalian vocabulary to establish dominance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this phrase means anything more than the words suggest:

> dogmatic — asserting opinions in a doctrinaire or arrogant manner; opinionated.

A "dogmatic gathering" would be a gathering where opinions are asserted in an arrogant manner.

In other words, the character remembers large words and uses them when everyone gathers in the yard to argue with each other.